# Does the Quran say that Allah has confused the minds of the infidels?

Tags: quran, source-identification

Does the Quran say somewhere that Allah has confused the minds of the infidels? I'm sure I read something like this before, but can't find the actual reference.

Comment: see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO_5u7w-RAE&feature=player_detailpage#t=1037s

Comment: yes, but only note that Allah never select who to guide and who to misguide! These are us who do something that prescribe further guidance or misguidance for us in the future.

Comment: @owari Allah is all knowing and all powerful, of course he select those of us he considers worthy to follow his path

Comment: @Hanif, yes you are right and we are saying one thing, that He selects but the selection is based on people themselves not because God a priory wants to guide someones ans misguide the others, otherwise that would be injustice whereas Allah is the Just ;)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean misguidance?

> ... So when they turned away (from the Path of Allah), Allah turned their hearts away (from the Right Path). And Allah guides not the people who are Fasiqun (the rebellious, the disobedient to Allah).
>   [Qur'an 61:5]
>
> Verily, those who disbelieve, it is the same to them whether you warn them or do not warn them, they will not believe.
>
> Allah has set a seal on their hearts and on their hearing,  (i.e they are closed from accepting Allah's Guidance), and on their eyes there is a covering. Theirs will be a great torment.
>   [Qur'an 2:6-7]
>
> Allah mocks at them and gives them increase in their wrong-doing to wander blindly.
>
> These are they who have purchased error for guidance, so their commerce was profitless. And they were not guided.
>
> Their likeness is as the likeness of one who kindled a fire; then, when it lighted all around him, Allah took away their light and left them in darkness. (So) they could not see.
>   [Qur'an 2:15-17]

Comment: Not sure. Qur'an 2:7 sounds like what I think I remember. Are you able to elaborate on what it means?

Comment: Added verse 6 for context. I'd assume it means exactly as it says.. a Muslim shouldn't worry too much about those who choose to disbelieve, there's no point to preaching to some of them, as it is Allah who ultimately guides someone to whether or not they believe. Those who deliberately choose to disbelief will be blinded/misguided by Allah anyway. The early part of this [Sura](http://quran.com/2) is rather self-explanatory and says it better than a few snippets could.

Comment: So do they disbelieve first, then Allah blinds/misguides them? Or does Allah blind/misguide first, which causes some people to disbelieve?

Comment: The language in the verse says that they are already disbelievers, and the early part of that Sura addresses mischievous troublemaker types. Combined with Verse 61:5, it seems that Allah deliberately misguides those who are purposely rebellious. This interpretation is to the best of my understanding; it would be appreciated if someone else has an alternative interpretation.

Comment: So the unbeliever is misguided/confused by Allah. I assume this misguidance/confusion relates to believing in Allah? Thus the unbeliever probably has very little chance in becoming a believer in Allah (since Allah is misguiding/confusing the person)?

Comment: Yes, it creates a feedback loop that pushes the person deeper into disbelief. _He[Allah] Guides therewith whom He wills; and whomever Allah sends astray, for him there is no guide._ [39:23]